# Writing a server using concepts of telnet

Tags: networking, telnet

I was given an assignment on networking which I have no clue of where to start.

This is the main part of the specification:

"You are expected to write a server that maintains a 'database' of your appointments (date, time, with whom, etc). All the usual operations such as searching, addition and deletion must be available. After your server has been activated, all interaction with it has to occur through Telnet. Your server is also responsible to echo everything that is entered.

To make your program more visually pleasing, you may use ANSI escape sequences that are supported by ANSI and VT100 (and other) emulations. Two of the more useful ANSI escape sequences are:

ESC[2J to clear the screen; and
ESC[y;xH to move the cursor to position (x,y) on the screen;"

So all I'm asking is which tools I need to complete this assignment?
And if there are any sources I can be provided to help me understand what to do it would be appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: Do you know which *language* you're going to be using ?

Comment: They did not specify. That's why I'm a bit lost. I know how to code with java, can java be used? @BrianAgnew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using Java, you should initially check out the [Java socket tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). In particular the server section of the [client/server tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) will give you a good starting point. I would expect you to write a server listening on a particular port.

You can then telnet to that port (`telnet localhost port_number`) and your server can then act on whatever you type into that telnet session.

I would worry about the ANSI side of things last of all, frankly.

Comment: They say that there should be a interaction with telnet. Will the socket programming cover this?

Comment: It would. See my amended answer above